# Despite the header file being in the same directory as the program, C can't find the file

Tags: c

According to one of the books I'm reading,

> When you write your own header files, use the second form of the preprocessor directive, the one that
> has quotation marks. When you use quotation marks, **C first searches the disk directory in which your
> program is stored and then searches the built-in #include directory.**

Program *TestingGrounds.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TestingExtensions.h"

main()
{
    printf("%d", NUM);
}
```

Header file *TestingExtensions.c*

```
#define NUM 21
```

The directory for both files is *MyFirstC*.

The Error I get is, *fatal error: TestingExtensions.h: No such file or directory*.

It works just fine if I use *#include "TestingExtensions.**c**"*.

---

I'm trying to imitate this example code:

```
// Example program #1 from Chapter 7 of Absolute Beginner's Guide to
// C, 3rd Edition
// File Chapter7ex1.c
/* This is a sample program that lists three kids and their school
supply needs, as well as cost to buy the supplies */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Chapter7ex1.h"
main()
{

int age;
char childname[14] = "Thomas";
printf("\n%s have %d kids.\n", FAMILY, KIDS);
age = 11;
printf("The oldest, %s, is %d.\n", childname, age);
strcpy(childname, "Christopher");
age = 6;
printf("The middle boy, %s, is %d.\n", childname, age);
age = 3;
strcpy(childname, "Benjamin");
printf("The youngest, %s, is %d.\n", childname, age);
return 0;
}
```

In this example, for a file named *Chapter7ex1.c*, *#include "Chapter7ex1.h"* is used. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Well, is the file called `TestingExtensions.c` or `TestingExtensions.h`?

Comment: There would've been a file called `Chapter7ex1.h` with all the function declarations, and another called `Chapter7ex1.c` with all the function definitions. Then in the main `.c` file (the one with the `main` function), we `#include "Chapter7ex1.h"` so that we have access to all the function declarations.

Comment: If the book uses `main()` rather than `int main()` or, preferably, `int main(void)`, you've got problems.  It was written for the C89 standard, not the C99, C11 or C17 (C18) standard.  That syntax for `main()` was always a bit sloppy, albeit commonly used, but has not been legitimate in the current C standard for the whole of this millennium.  Worry about what other bad practices it will lead you into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a directive `#include "TestingExtensions.h"` in your source code does not tell the compiler to read the file `TestingExtensions.c` and treat it as a header. The file name used in the `#include` directive must be the same as the name of the file in the file system.<sup>1</sup>

When you want to share some things from a source file with other source files, the general practice is:

- In a source file named `SomeFileName.c`, you **define** all functions and objects the source file provides to the program. Notably, you write functions with function bodies (the source code that implements the function), and you define objects with declarations such as `int MyVariable = 3;`.<sup>2</sup>
- In a header file named `SomeFileName.h`, you **declare** the identifiers of functions and objects you want to make known to other parts of the program. Notably, you declare functions without function bodies, as in `int MyFunction(int MyParameter);`, where there is no `{ … }` with the code for the function, and you declare variables without giving them initial values and using `extern`, as in `extern SomeType MyVariable;`.
- If the functions and variables you declare in the header file need special types, such as custom structures, you include definitions of those types in the header file.

From your comments, it appears you have a file named `TestingExtensions.c` that you are trying to include as `TestingExtensions.h`. You need to make a new file. Copy `TestingExtensions.c` to `TestingExtension.h` and edit it to make these changes:

- Delete everything that you do not want to share with the rest of the program. For example, if the file contains functions `foo` and `bar`, and you only want to share `foo`, then delete the code that defines `bar`.
- Replace all the function bodies (code in `{ … }`) with `;`, to change the function definitions to just declarations.
- Change all the definitions of variables to declarations. Generally, you want to avoid having external variables, especially external variables that are shared between source files. However, if you do, change them to declarations by removing any initializers and prefixing them with `extern`.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> A C implementation could translate header names from `#include` directives into different names in the file system. However, this was a feature that allowed the C language to be implemented in computers using file systems that treated names differently from how they appear in C source code, such as have limits on lengths or the cases of characters. In modern C implementations, the names in `#include` directives are almost always the same as the names in the file system, possibly with minor exceptions such as the character used to separate folders in paths.

<sup>2</sup> Due to the history of how C developed, which declarations define objects and which are merely declarations that describe an identifier but do not define an object are complicated. To be sure, a declaration that provides an initial value as with `= 3`, defines an object. A declaration that uses `extern` and does not provide an initial value does not define an object. Some other forms may depend on context.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your header file is called `TestingExtensions.h` exactly, including casing.  You need to add a `.h`. extension to `TestingExtensions`

Comment: Could you have a look at my edit? I'm having trouble understading why the book uses *#include "Chapter7ex1.h"* for a file named *Chapter7ex1.c*.

Comment: @Nameless If you are referring to the `Chapter7ex1.c` in the comment at the top of the code you are showing, then that is supposed to be the name of the file in which you put the shown code. `Chapter7ex1.h` is the other file with the `#define`s.